# How do HTTP conversations flow?

Tags: http, post

I know that clients and servers most commonly communicate through HTTP forms. I know enough about the GET methods, but the little I do know about POST methods is that they're used to submit data to the server. However, when the server receives a POST method and processes the data, it sends a status code like 200 etc., but **how does the server send more data?** I know there's a body but what does it look like? Does it have parameters and values just like a POST method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the body is specified in the `Content-Type` header.

A commonly used `Content-Type` for form data submission is [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). The body for such a request should look something like this:

```
key1=value1&key2=value+with+spaces
```

Where `key1` and `key2` are input names and `value1` and `value+with+spaces` are the corresponding values. Note that key names and values are [url encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Another common type is `application/json`, which means the request body should be interpreted as JSON data, for example:

```
{
    "key": "value",
    "another_key": "value"
}
```

So it's just data, and the `Content-Type` header tells the server how to interpret it.

**Edit:** A good way to see what's going on is create a form with `method="post"`, and analyze the request with your browser developer tools when the form is submitted.

Comment: So key1 and key2 are parameters/attributes similar to that of POST parameters, correct?

Comment: @soccerstar I think you mean similar to parameters in the URL e.g. `http://example.com/?key=value&key1=value1` that are used for forms with `method="get"`? If so, yes it is the same idea.

Comment: thank you. Also, how does the server send data back to the client?

Comment: @soccerstar exactly the same way - set a Content-Type header and just send the data in the body. For example the response for a standard GET request might have `Content-Type: text/html`, and the body is just the HTML page.